# Passing response header in Vuetable api-mode

Tags: vue.js, axios, authorization, response-headers, vue-tables-2

I am wondering if there is a way to use `api-mode` and still be able to pass a response header such as an authorisation token.

Vuetable consumes this `api-url` prop and use it to make a GET request. How do I pass in a response header when this happens?

```
<vuetable
            ref="vuetable"
            :api-url="apiBase"
            :query-params="makeQueryParams"
            :per-page="perPage"
            pagination-path
            :reactive-api-url="true"
            :fields="fields"
            :row-class="onRowClass"
            @vuetable:pagination-data="onPaginationData"
            @vuetable:cell-rightclicked="rightClicked"
          >
```

I am hoping to pass in a response header, if it was `axios` it would be done like this.

```
const response = await axios.get(this.apiBase, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${$cookies.get('token')}`}
    })
```

The documentation does say that it can be done by setting `api-mode` to false and use `data-mode`. That way, I will have full control of the api and data. But that means that I would sacrifice [query-params](https://www.vuetable.com/api/vuetable/properties.html#query-params) that enables me to make use of the library's pagination and sorting function. Generally I would lose a lot of built in functions of `vuetable` if I go with `data-mode` instead of `api-mode`, so I would much prefer to go with `api-mode`.

Relevant documentation: https://www.vuetable.com/api/vuetable/properties.html#api-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer from this [thread](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2/issues/365) in github.

```
<vuetable :http-options="httpOptions" ...
```

and in JS

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            httpOptions: { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + TOKEN } },
            ...
```